# While loop python resulting in infinite loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

```
def generate_n_chars(n,s="."):
    res=""
    count=0
    while count < n:
        count=count+1
        res=res+s

    return res

print generate_n_chars(raw_input("Enter the integer value : "),raw_input("Enter the character : "))
```

I am beginner in python and I don't know why this loop going to infinity. Please someone correct my program

Comment: Can you add what inputs you used?

Comment: You're comparing a number with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the input will be evaluated and set to a string. Therefore, you're comparing two variables of different types. You need to cast your input to an integer.

```
def generate_n_chars(n,s="."):
  res=""
  count=0
  while count < n:
    count=count+1
    res=res+s

generate_n_chars(int(raw_input("Enter the integer value : ")),raw_input("Enter the character : "))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def generate_n_chars(n, s = "."):
    res = ""
    count = 0
    while count < n:
        count = count + 1
        res = res + s

    return res

print generate_n_chars(input("Enter the integer value : "), raw_input("Enter the character : "))
```

Here `input("Enter the integer value : ")` `input` instead of `raw_input`

`raw_input()` => https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

`input()` =>  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input